# MuPAD: How to determine just the existence of solutions to a set of linear inequalities?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, simplex, mupad

Using MuPAD, I want to find out if *at least one solution* exists for a set of of linear inequalities. For example, the following system of linear inequalities:

[image]

which I solve in MuPAD by:

```
solve({x+z>2*y,z>y,2*z>2*x,x>0,y>0,z>0},{x,y,z}
```

and MuPAD returns the set of solutions, in some type of notation:

[image]

However, I do not care about the exact form of the solution set, i.e., whether it is finite, or infinite, I just care if there is at least one viable solution.

I would like to call MuPAD from Matlab, ask if a solution set exists to the inequalities, and then get back a "yes" or "no" answer. I could test for the empty set being returned, but I do not know how to test if a symbolic variable represents the empty set.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example – in Matlab or MuPAD code – with cases that meet these two conditions (one or more solutions and no solutions)? We can't really help if you don't at least show the code/functions you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using MuPAD's [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/solve.html) and `sym/isempty` [called from Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html):

```
syms x y z;
~isempty(feval(symengine,'solve',[x+z>2*y,z>y,2*z>2*x,x>0,y>0,z>0],[x y z]))
~isempty(feval(symengine,'solve',[x+z>2*y,z>y,2*z>2*x,x>0,y>0,z<0],[x y z]))
```

The first case returns true, `1`, indicating that there is at least one solution. The second returns false, `0`, as there is no solution.

If you want to do this within MuPAD, you can use the [`is`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/is.html) function:

```
not(is(solve([x+z>2*y,z>y,2*z>2*x,x>0,y>0,z>0],[x,y,z])={}))
not(is(solve([x+z>2*y,z>y,2*z>2*x,x>0,y>0,z<0],[x,y,z])={}))
```

However, the first case will return [`UNKNOWN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/unknown.html), which is rather difficult to deal with. You may want to use something like the following instead:

```
is(length(solve([x+z>2*y,z>y,2*z>2*x,x>0,y>0,z>0],[x,y,z]))>1)
is(length(solve([x+z>2*y,z>y,2*z>2*x,x>0,y>0,z<0],[x,y,z]))>1)
```

which assumes that only an empty solution, Ø, will have a [`length`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/length.html) of one. (The MuPAD code is two characters, `{}`, but it displays as one, Ø, has a length of one, and means empty/zero.) There are probably other ways.

Comment: Thanks for your help horchler, using `length` seems to work acceptably. On another note, rather disconcertingly, MuPad reports solutions exist for the following inequality set: `solve({(2*y)>(x+z),x>y,z>x,x>0,y>0,z>0},{x,y,z})`, where by my logic there can be none!

Comment: @edison1093: Glad to help. I'm not particularly familiar with systems of inequalities. You might try a simple plot (using `plot3` in Matlab or something in MuPAD) of the regions of interest. Just split the planes/surfaces of equality to begin with, i.e, `(2*y)=(x+z)`,`x=y`,`z=x`, over  some range of `x`, `y`, and `z` starting from zero.